# Is this request frequency limiter thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

In order to prevent excessive server pressure, I implemented a request frequency limiter using a sliding window algorithm, which can determine whether the current request is allowed to pass according to the parameters. In order to achieve the thread safety of the algorithm, I used the atomic type to control the number of sliding steps of the window, and used unique_lock to achieve the correct sum of the total number of requests in the current window.
But I'm not sure whether my implementation is thread-safe, and if it is safe, whether it will affect service performance. Is there a better way to achieve it?

```
class SlideWindowLimiter
{
public:
  bool TryAcquire();
  void SlideWindow(int64_t window_number);

private:
  int32_t limit_;   // maximum number of window requests
  int32_t split_num_;   // subwindow number
  int32_t window_size_; // the big window
  int32_t sub_window_size_;  // size of subwindow = window_size_ / split_number
  
  int16_t index_{0};  //the index of window vector
  std::mutex mtx_;
  std::vector<int32_t> sub_windows_;  // window vector 
  std::atomic<int64_t> start_time_{0};  //start time of limiter
}

bool SlideWindowLimiter::TryAcquire() {
   int64_t cur_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
   auto time_stamp = start_time_.load();
   int64_t window_num = std::max(cur_time - window_size_ - start_time_, int64_t(0)) / sub_window_size_;
    
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(mtx_, std::defer_lock);
   if (window_num > 0  && start_time_.compare_exchange_strong(time_stamp, start_time_.load() + window_num*sub_window_size_)) {
     guard.lock();
     SlideWindow(window_num);
     guard.unlock();
   }
 
   monitor_->TotalRequestQps();
   {
     guard.lock();
     int32_t total_req = 0;
     std::cout<<" "<<std::endl;
     for(auto &p : sub_windows_) {
       std::cout<<p<<" "<<std::this_thread::get_id()<<std::endl;
       total_req += p;
     }
 
     if(total_req >= limit_) {
       monitor_->RejectedRequestQps();
       return false;
     } else {
       monitor_->PassedRequestQps();
       sub_windows_[index_] += 1;
       return true;
     }
     guard.unlock();
   }
 }

void SlideWindowLimiter::SlideWindow(int64_t window_num) {
   int64_t slide_num = std::min(window_num, int64_t(split_num_));  
   for(int i = 0; i < slide_num; i++){
     index_ += 1;
     index_ = index_ % split_num_;
     sub_windows_[index_] = 0;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thread-safe is a **relative** property.  Two sequences of operations are thread-safe relative to each other.  A single bit of code cannot be thread-safe by itself.

I'll instead answer "am I handling threading in such a way that reasonable thread-safety guarantees could be made with other reasonable code".

The answer is "No".

I found one concrete problem; your use of atomic and `compare_exchange_strong` isn't in a loop, and you access `start_time_` atomically at multiple spots without the proper care.    If `start_time_` changes in the period with the 3 spots you read and write from it, you return false, and fail to call `SlideWindow`, then... proceed as if you had.

I can't think of why that would be a reasonable response to contention, so that is a "No, this code isn't written to behave reasonably under multiple threads using it".

---

There is a lot of bad smell in your code.  You are mixing concurrency code with a whole pile of state, which means it isn't clear what mutexes are guarding what data.

You have a pointer in your code that is never defined.  Maybe it is supposed to be a global variable?

You are writing to `cout` using multiple `<<` on one line.  That is a bad plan in a multithreaded environment; even if your `cout` is concurrency-hardened, you get scrambled output.  Build a buffer string and do one `<<`.

You are passing data between functions via the back door.  `index_` for example.  One function sets a member variable, another reads it.  Is there any possibility it gets edited by another thread?  Hard to audit, but seems reasonably likely; you set it on one `.lock()`, then `.unlock()`, then read it as if it was in a sensible state in a later `lock()`.  What more, you use it to access a vector; if the vector or index changed in unplanned ways, that could crash or lead to memory corruption.

...

I would be shocked if this code didn't have a pile of race conditions, crashes and the like in production.  I see no sign of any attempt to prove that this code is concurrency safe, or simplify it to the point where it is easy to sketch such a proof.

In actual real practice, any code that you haven't **proven** is concurrency safe is going to be unsafe to use concurrently.  So complex concurrency code is almost guaranteed to be unsafe to use concurrently.

...

Start with a really, really simple model.  If you have a mutex and some data, make that mutex and the data into a single struct, so you know exactly what that mutex is guarding.

If you are messing with an atomic, don't use it in the middle of other code mixed up with other variables.  Put it in its own class.  Give that class a name, representing some concrete semantics, ideally ones that you have found elsewhere.  Describe what it is supposed to do, and what the methods guarantee before and after.  Then *use that*.

Elsewhere, avoid any kind of global state.  This includes class member variables used to pass state around.  Pass your data explicitly from one function to another.  Avoid pointers to anything mutable.

If your data is all value types in automatic storage and pointers to immutable (never changing in the lifetime of your threads) data, that data can't be directly involved in a race condition.

The remaining data is bundled up and firewalled in a small a spot as possible, and you can look at how you interact with it and determine if you are messing up.

...

Multithreaded programming is hard, especially in an environment with mutable data.  If you aren't working to make it possible to prove your code is correct, you are going to produce code that isn't correct, and you won't know it.

Well, based off my experience, I know it; all code that isn't obviously trying to act in such a way that it is *easy* to show it is correct is simply incorrect.  If the code is old and has piles of patches over a decade+, the incorrectness is probably unlikely and harder to find, but it is probably still incorrect.  If it is new code, it is probably easier to find the incorrectness.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed comments and suggestions, and I have benefited a lot. I did not post the complete code, so some places look strange. I will edit it again. And about  ”if `start_time_` changes in the period with the 3 spots you read and write from it, you return false, and fail to call SlideWindow, then... proceed as if you had“ , I'm a little confused.

Comment: I use CAS to ensure that the algorithm can only slide once in a new time sub-window. Because there may be such a scenario: almost at the same time, multiple requests arrive, and the timestamp at this time is long enough to cause a sub-window sliding. The correct algorithm is that after the window is sliding and the start time is updated, other requests at this moment or in the future only need to be counted in the number of requests for the current sub-window, until the timestamp minus the current `start_time_ ` is  long enough to generate a new sliding.

Comment: CAS is actually used to update `start_time_` correctly.

Comment: @salmon only if you don't care about inaccuracy or assume code is fast compared to clocks.  Two threads with the same start time, and differing window nums, who contend at the CAS whichever is first updates, the other is ignored.  Then both log to whichever window wins.  Trying to write out pre/post conditions, you can't get reasonable ones.  It works if you don't care you are sometimes logging to the wrong window.  I could be wrong and there could be worse problems; when there aren't simple strong and sensible guarantees, it is sometimes hard to tell how wrong it can get.

Comment: When two threads with the same start time come, one touch the CAS to update `start_time_` casue CAS return `true` and the `index_` will be updated meanwhile in body of the `if`, after that, it will be counted to the new subwindow (`index_` controls the window current thread belong to), and though the other thread touch the CAS with false return, it will be counted into the same subwindow as the first one(now, two threads may have same `start_time` and `index_` which are variables of the class SlideWindowLimiter)

Comment: Also, the other thread could be counted into the pre subwindow (when the first thread have not update the `index_` in `if`), but the `total_req` decide if access the request by comparing with limit_num, so it is safe in logic of a limiter function.